# Heroku error H14 "no web processes running"

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

When I trying to open my app in Heroku, I receive this message:

> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
> heroku logs --tail

heroku logs --tail :

> 2021-11-25T18:34:03.593007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processed=GET path="/" host=football-players-stats-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a5af4869-7e84-46a69b fwd="186.58.9.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2021-11-25T18:34:12.174019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processed=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=football-players-stats-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e168a97-4c41a2513edb fwd="186.58.9.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=ht

This is my Procfile

> web: gunicorn app.wsgi --log-file -

Comands

heroku ps:scale web=1:

> Scaling dynos... !
> !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

heroku ps

> Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 1000h 0m (100%)
> Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
> For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping
> No dynos on ⬢ football-players-stats-api

I did this but it still doesn't work.

> heroku buildpacks:clear
> heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
> git commit --allow-empty -m "Adjust push heroku master"
> git push master

I dont know where is the problem.
Id really appreciate if you could help me.

Here is me repo, if you need to see it
https://github.com/Garridot/Football_players_stats_Api/tree/main/app

Comment: "Couldn't find that process type (web)"—this suggests your `Procfile` is not correct. Are you sure it's called `Procfile`, exactly? Is it in the root directory?

Comment: You are right, Procfile was not correct, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

i used:   web:gunicorn app:app instead of
web: gunicorn app:app
so take one space after web:

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this command :

`echo "web: gunicorn app:app" > Procfile`

instead create Procfile manually and copy the `web: gunicorn app:app` into it